# Magento 2.4.5 - Minicart actions not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

Please check the attached image.
[image]

This happens when the customer adds the product to the cart.
And can't go to the checkout page, or cart page, and can't remove items in Mini-Cart.

The magento version is 2.4.5
I think it's related to the version upgrades. But I am not sure.
Can you let me know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score -2):

2.4.5 The product cannot be added to the shopping cart, cannot be settled, and the checkout page is blank